# Как передать данные в ФНС по ФЗ-54?

Tags: python

Новый 54-ФЗ обязывает всех, кто оказывает услуги физлицам, передавать каждую транзакцию в ФНС. Многие программисты это делают через онлайн-кассы, оплачивая им ~50тыс в год, но если требуется передавать всего пару платежей, наверняка проще это делать самому скриптом. Подскажите, кто как это делает на python.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что SO - это не сервис по оказанию юридических услуг.

Comment: Увы, у меня нет такой возможности, а удаление  SO не рекомендует, если есть ответ, да ещё и по существу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Закон предписывает не передавать транзакции в ФНС, а использовать фискальный накопитель (ФН), вместо ЭКЛЗ, который подготавливает и подтверждает данные для передачи в ОФД (оператор фискальных данных). ФН и онлайн-касса - не одно и тоже. Сам по себе ФН работать не может, а без него касса - просто принтер чеков.
По ценам да, не очень приятно: плата ОФД - 3000 руб./год, новая простенькая касса ~ 8000 руб., ФН (который будет меняться либо раз в год, либо в 3 года, смотря какая версия) - 10000руб..

Comment: Хм, видимо, я неверно понял схему. То есть для нерегулярных разовых расчётов как раз нужен не монстр типа atol, а закону достаточно иметь простой ОФД (передаёт данные в ФНС) + физическая касса + к ней ФН? Если так, то зачем фактически нужен ФН для тех, кто и раньше работал без чеков, а по простым переводам по квитанции на реквизиты?

Comment: Да в общем и неясно, зачем физически прибор, если клиент оплачивает онлайн, и ему даже физически чек не получается отдать. ОФД, как я понял, сможет чек послать клиенту сам.